# Show that $ 0 \leq \int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2) dx \leq \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus

Show that $ 0 \leq \int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2) dx \leq \frac{1}{3}$

I know that the function $\sin$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Then I could say that $0 \leq \sin(x^2) \leq 1$

Any hint to keep going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use convexity of $\sin$ on $[0,1]$ to argue $\sin u \leq u$.

---

**Details:**

We actually know that $$0 \leq \sin u \leq \min(1,u), \qquad u\in[0,1]$$ Why? The fact that $\sin \leq 1$ is obvious; the other, we have $\sin'' = -\sin$ which is negative on $[0,1]$, from which on $[0,1]$ $\sin u \leq \sin 0 + \sin'(0) u = u$ by convexity.

This implies
$$0 \leq \sin(x^2) \leq x^2, \qquad x\in[0,1]$$

But $\int_0^{1} x^2 dx = 1/3$.

Comment: To see that $\sin x \leq x$, look at the unit circle with angle $x$ in standard position.  The arc subtended by $x$ is $x$ units long.  Clearly longer than the leg of the right triangle representing $\sin x.$

Comment: Isn't that usually called *concave?*

Comment: @B.Goddard Sure, that's another proof.

Comment: @MartinR $\sin$ is concave there. But the property used is convexity (i.e., I refer by "properties following from convexity" to "properties of functions which follow from their being either convex or concave").

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\bigl(\forall x\in[0,\infty)\bigr):\sin(x)\leqslant x$